# Indentify different types of triangle

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm

I'm trying to write a code to indentify different types of triangle. But when the function is activated, there is no alert. Here's my code:

```
function alertf(){
            var a=document.getElementById("a").value;
            var b=document.getElementById("b").value;
            var c=document.getElementById("c").value;
            if((sqr(a)+sqr(b)==sqr(c))||(sqr(a)+sqr(c)==sqr(b))||(sqr(b)+sqr(c)==sqr(a))) 
                     alert("Right triangle")                                                
            else if((a==b)||(b==c)||(a==c)) alert("Isosceles triangle")
                else if((a==b)&&(a==c)) alert("Equilateral triangle")
                  else alert("Ordinary triangle");
```

Comment: This isn't answering your question, but you should test for equilateral before isosceles.

Comment: Open your JS console (F12, `Console` tab), and you might see an error telling you what is going wrong. The main thing I see here is that you are using a `sqr` function, which does not exist natively in JS. Have you declared it in your code? If not, add it: `function sqr(n) { return Math.pow(n, 2); }`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something along these lines:

```js
function sqr(x) {
    return Math.pow(x, 2);
}

function showOutput(output) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
}

function alertf(){
    var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c").value;

    if((sqr(a)+sqr(b)==sqr(c))||(sqr(a)+sqr(c)==sqr(b))||(sqr(b)+sqr(c)==sqr(a))) {
        showOutput("Right triangle");
    } else if((a==b)&&(a==c)) {
        showOutput("Equilateral triangle");
    } else if((a==b)||(b==c)||(a==c)) {
        showOutput("Isosceles triangle");
    } else {
        showOutput("Ordinary triangle");
    }
}

alertf();
```

```html
Side A length: <input id="a" value="3" onchange="alertf()"></input><br>
Side B length: <input id="b" value="4" onchange="alertf()"></input><br>
Side C length: <input id="c" value="5" onchange="alertf()"></input><br><br>
Output:<div id="output"><div>
```